# Inserting balance data on a relational database table

Tags: mysql

I'm using relational database(MySQL). On this database i have a table called customer_transaction. On this table i have 4 columns: **id, customer_id, type, amount**

```
|id|customer_id |type     |amount|
|--|------------|---------|------|
|1 |44          |Credit   |50    |
|2 |44          |Credit   |20    |
|3 |44          |Debit    |30    |
```

I want to introduce a balance column(current balance) on this table like below.

```
|id|customer_id |type     |amount|balance|
|--|------------|---------|------|-------|
|1 |44          |Credit   |50    |50     |
|2 |44          |Credit   |20    |70     |
|3 |44          |Debit    |30    |40     |
```

two possible approaches are:

1. when a row inserted onto the table, MySQL automatically (a procedure or something) calculates the balance and insert into the balance field.
2. Or calculating balance on application layer and insert in to DB.

So i want to know which approach is better and it's great if any one can suggest me any example of **number 1** approach. But their is another concern, if i want to delete a row, then how to re-sync all balance the data?

Comment: Don't insert on db think of the mess you would have to sort out if there were contras. AND what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon, i'm using mysql 5.7

Comment: Every insert will require a recalculation of the balance, if the insert is between already existing transactions (ie backdated) then you have to recalculate the balance, every typo correction you have to recalculate the balance BUT you should never have a period end balance which does not agree with a period end statement.

Comment: What that means is you had better be sure at statement time the balance is fully justifiable whenever you look at your db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, which should work on any version of MySQL:

```
SELECT
    id,
    customer_id,
    type,
    amount,
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Credit' THEN amount ELSE -1.0* amount END)
     FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS balance
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    customer_id,
    id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

On MySQL 8+, we can take advantage of analytic functions, to avoid writing the lengthy correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    id,
    customer_id,
    type,
    amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Credit' THEN amount ELSE -1.0* amount END) OVER
        (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id) AS balance
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    customer_id,
    id;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen, i have another question, when a new row is inserted, how mysql will handle it on it's own?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if you're asking what "order" the record has, the answer is, there is no internal order to a MySQL table.  Actually, instead of using the `id` to determine the order of transactions, you should use something like a timestamp.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. What I meant to ask was- suppose i am inserting new rows in the table above. Now there will be a new balance. should I process this balance through a mysql ' procedure'  or " function" ?